# jQuery change id on transition end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a short jQuery function, that is responsible for changing the background. The thing is, if I click the button again, it just skips the whole transition and start the next one.  What I wanted to do here was change the button id until the transition end, so the user won't be able to skip it.

JS

```
function changeBackground(div, arrowLeft, arrowRight, array, i){
  $(arrowLeft).attr("id", "#arrow-left-wait");
  $(arrowRight).attr("id", "#arrow-right-wait");
  $(div).css("background-image", `url(img/${backgrounds[i]})`);
  $(div).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
  function(){
    $("#arrow-left-wait").attr("id", arrowLeft);
    $("#arrow-right-wait").attr("id", arrowRight);
  });
  return;
}
```

CSS

```
.text{
  min-height: 500px;
  background-image: url("../img/background_1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: background-image 1500ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1500ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: background-image 1500ms ease-in;;
}
```

Comment: Remove # in your code. But the logic incorrect there are many other ways to disable the element then changing the id.

Comment: Why would you change the Id for the buttons. That’s a bad practice.

Comment: Well, that was just the first thing that came to my mind, if you know any better ways to do that, I'm happy to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need jQuery for this, just add the following code to your file in a `<script>` element:

```js
document.getElementById('this').id = 'changed';
```

```html
<div id="this">
</div>
```

This will change the id of the `<div id="this">` to `<div id="changed">`!

Ask if you need a more thorough explanation, and I can post it on my website if you want me to.

JBDouble05

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for! Sadly, It won't work like I wanted to and I have to find a proper way to do this.